# SonarCloud in GitHub doesn't recognise C# 12 primary constructors

Tags: c#, github, sonarcloud

SonarCloud in GitHub doesn't recognise C# 12 primary constructors and this triggers various false negatives in validation rules.

One example is below, here Sonar interprets a class with primary constructor as an empty class - which is not empty. There are other issues, but it seems like SonarCloud is either not up to date or some configuration might be required?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be a bug with SonarCloud, based on how new the C#12 features are. Are the developers aware of it?

Comment: Even ReSharper, the gold standard, doesn't support C# 12 yet. 2023.3 EAP 8 chokes on collection initializers for example

Answer (score 1):

Looks like C# 12 is not supported yet. On [their website](https://www.sonarsource.com/knowledge/languages/csharp/) it states that ATM (Nov-2023):

> Language Versions
>
> - To C#**11**

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging found this :

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/net-8-and-c-12-support/103931

> We now find issues in the new syntax in C#12 such as primary constructors, collection expressions, inline arrays, optional parameters in lambdas, ref readonly parameters and type aliases.

Looks like we'll have to wait until it's sorted out.